# How do I troubleshoot a crashing Android webview (due to rich JS / interactions)?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I'm using a Droid X, running Android 2.2. I am a client side web dev.

I have some rich functionality (ajax call, spinner, dom access to reinject results).

On of the interactions makes the webview crash. It is not crashing on other android devices (the ones I've tested at least). It also doesn't crash on iPhone or iPad.

Isolating specifically what part of the JavaScript is crashing the webview (I assume it's the JS) is proving to be very difficult.

Anybody have tips on how I can effectively troubleshoot this so I patch my code so the webview won't crash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: There isn't an easy way that I found. I just had to try to isolate the code as much as possible. It's a good idea to keep the JS decoupled and modular so you can pull out 1 piece, and then run the page without causing errors all over the place. This makes troubleshooting issues like the one above much easier as well.